# How to use existing Oracle sequence to generate id in hibernate?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, sequence

I have legacy Oracle db with a sequence named `PRODUCT_ID_SEQ`.

Here is the mapping of `Product` class for which I need generate correct ids:

```
public class Product {
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, 
                       generator = "retailerRaw_seq")
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "retailerRaw_seq", 
                      sequenceName = "PRODUCT_ID_SEQ")
   private Long id;

   ...
}
```

But looks like ids are generated with an interval of 50, like 1000, 1050, 1100 etc. This corresponds to the default value of `allocationSize` property = 50. So that means that Hibernate doesn't actually use the sequence which is already defined in the db.

How do I make Hibernate use the sequence?

Comment: Duplicate question: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729723/hibernate-does-not-generate-identifier-when-using-oracle-sequence/1729753#1729753

Comment: No, it isn't a duplicate. See below for the answer

Answer (score 29):

The answer to the original question:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name="EL_SEQ", sequenceName="EL_SEQ",allocationSize=1)
```

It is `allocationSize` that sets the value to increment by.

Comment: Upvoted because this is a correct JPA solution rather than being Hibernate specific. However an allocationSize=1 means that a number needs to be obtained from the database for every insert rather than caching a lot of Ids at once, so it comes with a very small performance degradation.

Answer (score 20):

I'm not used to use annotations, this is what I have in my *.hbm.xml:

```
<id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
    <column name="ID_PRODUCT" />
    <generator class="sequence-identity" >
        <param name="sequence">PRODUCT_ID_SEQ</param>
    </generator>
</id>
```

You can easily map this to annotations. The generator *sequence-identity* uses auto increment with sequences.

Comment: This is the right way to do it (with xml) see below for an example with annotations

Comment: +1 and remember to add `<property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys">true</property>` in your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a working example with annotations, this way, the existing DB sequence will be used (you can also use the "sequence" strategy, but with less performance on insertion) :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {

    // (...)

    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "sequence-identity", parameters = @Parameter(name = "sequence", value = "USER_SEQ"))
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 22, scale = 0)
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
```

Comment: I found when using this technique it worked but my Database was incrementing it's id value by 2 instead of 1. Any ideas why?

Comment: check your sequence definition in Oracle, you may have something like "CREATE SEQUENCE my_sequence START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 2"

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue while upgrading from 3.5.5 to 5.0.6.Final.

I solved it by re-configuring mapping in the HBM file from:

```
    <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">PRODUCT_ID_SEQ</param>
    </generator>
```

to:

```
    <generator class="org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator"> 
        <param name="prefer_sequence_per_entity">true</param> 
        <param name="optimizer">none</param>
        <param name="increment_size">1</param>
        <param name="sequence_name">PRODUCT_ID_SEQ</param>
    </generator>
```

Comment: Is it necessary to set increment_size to 1?  Isn't it the default value?

Answer (score 5):

Create your sequence name in Oracle, for example, contacts_seq.
In Your POJO Class . Define the following annotation for your sequence.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="my_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name="my_seq_gen", sequenceName="contacts_seq")
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator, hibernate use hilo and will possibly create large gaps in the sequence. There is a post addressing this problem: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=973682

there are two ways to fix this problem

1. In the SequenceGenerator annotation, add allocationSize = 1, initialValue= 1
2. instead of using javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator, use org.hibernate.annotations, like this:

   @javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator(name = "Question_id_sequence", sequenceName = "S_QUESTION")

   @org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(name="Question_id_sequence", strategy = "sequence", parameters = { @Parameter(name="sequence", value="S_QUESTION") } )

I have tested both ways, which works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

**allocationSize** and **incrementBy** are completely different things.

Hibernate is of course using your sequence created in DB but depending on allocationSize you might find gap in generated value.

For example- 
Let assume current sequence value is 5, **increment by 1 in db**, and  **allocationSize** default 50.

Now you want to save a collection of 3 element through hibernate, then 
Hibernate will assign generated id 250, 251, 252

This is for optimization purpose. Hibernate doesn't have to go back to db and fetch next incremented value.

If you don't want this just setting `allocationSize = 1` as already answered will do the purpose

Answer (score 1):

I use following on PostgreSQL and works just fine.

```
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(generator = "my_gen")
 @SequenceGenerator(name = "my_gen", sequenceName = "my_seq_in_db")
 private int userId;
```

Comment: PostgreSQL and Oracle is different database types

Answer (score 0):

By default Hibernate uses sequence HiLo generator which ,unless you have special needs, it is good (performance wise). You can read more of that in my blog [here](http://blog.eyallupu.com/2011/01/hibernatejpa-identity-generators.html)

Eyal

Comment: Any idea to change algorithm, saying to pooled instead of hilo using JPA annotations?

Answer (score 0):

First : you should create in your database the sequence like:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "PRODUCT_ID_SEQ"  MINVALUE 0 MAXVALUE 1000000000 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 500 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
```

and in your file Product.hbm.xml configuration make :

```
 <class name="ProductPersistant" table="Product">

    <id  name="id"  type="java.lang.Long" column="productID" >
          <generator class="sequence"> 
               <param name="sequence">PRODUCT_ID_SEQ</param>   
          </generator>
    </id>
```