# How to return max of identity column via Hibernate accessing Oracle DB?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

Since it seems that HQL (createQuery) doesn't support scalar queries, I used a raw query via createSQLQuery:

```
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select nvl(max(id), 0) + 1  from empty_table_for_now");

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        List listL = query.list();
        Iterator iterator = listL.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            LOG.info("Infinite loop. This is disgusting!");
        }
```

The query itself doesn't fail, but it seems to be returning a list with an **infinite** number of results? This doesn't make sense... Any idea why I am getting this?

Even better yet, is there a better, more elegant way, of getting the intended scalar, without having to confuse whoever maintains my code with a "list" (that should always contain one element)?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `select max(..)` to generate unique values. It's either incorrect or will not scale. Use a sequence instead

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks. You are right of course but in my particular case a sequence is an overkill (comes with own problems, too). I will stick with `max()` for now since I will always have only one process creating and/or updating this table.

Comment: The `max()` approach is a much bigger "overkill". Especially on large tables the query will be really slow whereas using a sequence is **a lot** faster.

Comment: Once again you are right, but in my particular case performance is not an issue. OTOH, sequences tend to get out of sync (or max out) in organizations in which the DBAs don't talk to the developers and in which the tail is wagging the dog. ;) Then again, I just saw @PRK's answer so if I can get Hibernate to handle this for me, I will definitely take the correct route.

Comment: Sequences don't "max out". Their max value is 10^28. So even if you get a thousand values per second it would take ages to max it out.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Unless someone at Oracle, implementing CC&B,  decides to force a MAX_VALUE of 999 on a sequence... But in principle, yes you are right (again).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't move the iterator the loop is definitely infinite (as long as there is at least one element).

Move the iterator with [Iterator.next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next%28%29)

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Object nextElement = iterator.next();
    LOG.info("Next element is: " + nextElement);
}
```

Maybe you had a [ResultSet.next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) in mind when writing the code, but an iterator is different. Take a look at the javadocs.

Comment: Duh! I should have know better. Thank you for pointing out my moment of blindness. +1 and accepting.

Answer (score 4):

When using Oracle DB, I recommend the use of sequences.

To get the sequence to work, you should define the column and the sequence name in the mapping file and Hibernate will do the job of fetching the next sequence value.

FYI:
SQL Server - Use Identity for autoincrement
MySQL/Maria DB - Use autoincrement
PostgreSQL - Use sequences or alternatively ..
[PostgreSQL Autoincrement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787722/postgresql-autoincrement)

Alert: Trying to find the maximum value in a column and bouncing it up is not an acceptable design.

Comment: Thanks +1 for the tip regarding Hibernate doing the job of fetching the next sequence value by simply defining something in the `hbm.xml` file. Where can I learn more about this? A concrete example would be super. Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082175/how-to-use-sequence-in-hibernate-as-a-property-in-xml-mapping

Comment: Detailed examples  at .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155376/how-to-use-existing-oracle-sequence-to-generate-id-in-hibernate