# sequence generators are getting ignored

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, jboss, annotations

I'm getting the following error while saving a object. However similar configuration is working for other model objects in my projects. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENROLLMENT_GROUP_MEMBERSHIPS", schema = "LEAD_ROUTING")
public class EnrollmentGroupMembership implements Serializable, Comparable,Auditable {
    @javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator(name = "enrollmentGroupMemID", sequenceName = "S_ENROLLMENT_GROUP_MEMBERSHIPS")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "enrollmentGroupMemID")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;


@ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "TIER_WEIGHT_OID", referencedColumnName = "OID", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private TierWeight tierWeight;

    public EnrollmentGroupMembership() {

    }

}
```

Code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TIER_WEIGHT", schema = "LEAD_ROUTING")
public class TierWeight implements Serializable, Auditable {

@SequenceGenerator(name = "tierSequence",sequenceName = "S_TIER_WEIGHT")
    @Column(name = "OID")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "tierSequence")
    private Long id;

@OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "TIER_WEIGHT_OID", referencedColumnName = "OID")
    private Set<EnrollmentGroupMembership> memberships;


    public TierWeight() {
    }
}
```

The logic layer's code is

```
@Override
    public void createTier(String tierName, float weight) {
        TierWeight tier = new TierWeight();
        tier.setWeight(weight);
        tier.setTier(tierName);
        tierWeightDAO.create(tier);
    }
```

Similar Many-one configuration is working through out the project. I don't know why this one instance is failing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The following is the error that I'm getting

> Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException:
>   ids for this class must be manually
>   assigned before calling save():
>   edu.apollogrp.d2ec.model.TierWeight at
>   org.hibernate.id.Assigned.generate(Assigned.java:3
>   3) at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.
>   saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java
>   :99)

The log file is telling that the sequence generator tierSequence is not getting created. However other sequence generators are getting created.

> 2010-06-03 11:24:51,834 DEBUG
>   [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder:]
>   Processing annotations of
>   edu.apollogrp.d2ec.model.TierWeight.dateCreated
>   2010-06-03 11:24:51,834 DEBUG
>   [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder:]
>   Processing annotations of
>   edu.apollogrp.d2ec.model.TierWeight.dateCreated
>   2010-06-03 11:24:51,834 DEBUG
>   [org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column:]
>   Binding column DATE_CREATED unique
>   false
>
> .......................................
>   .......................................
>   2010-06-03 11:24:51,756 DEBUG
>   [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder:]
>   Processing annotations of
>   edu.apollogrp.d2ec.model.CounselorAvailability.id
>   2010-06-03 11:24:51,756 DEBUG
>   [org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column:]
>   Binding column OID unique false
>   2010-06-03 11:24:51,756 DEBUG
>   [org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column:]
>   Binding column OID unique false
>   2010-06-03 11:24:51,756 DEBUG
>   [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder:]
>   id is an id 2010-06-03 11:24:51,756
>   DEBUG
>   [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder:]
>   id is an id 2010-06-03 11:24:51,756
>   DEBUG
>   [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder:]
>   Add sequence generator with name:
>   counselorAvailabilityID 2010-06-03
>   11:24:51,756 DEBUG
>   [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder:]
>   Add sequence generator with name:
>   counselorAvailabilityID

---

While debugging, I see that the org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl is returning the "Assigned" identifierGenerator. This is horrible. I've specified the identifierGenerator as "Auto". Please see the above code.

As a sidenote, I was trying to debug and seeing how the objects are getting retrieved from the database. Looks like the enrollmentgroupmembership records have the tierweight value populated. However if I look at the tierweight object, it doesn't have the enrollmentgroupmembership records. I'm puzzled. I think these two problems must be related.

Maddy.

Comment: @luvfort Maybe you wnat to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729723/hibernate-does-not-generate-identifier-when-using-oracle-sequence

Answer (score 0):

I guess @OneToMany configuration should be like below.

- @OneToMany(mappedBy="tierWeight")